# Windows Store App: Dynamically load JavaScript for easier update?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps

Recently I have taken over a Windows Store app project written in `C#/XAML` and one of its requirements is,

Migrating the project to `Javascript/HTML5`, and by making javascript dynamically loaded from our website, we can update the code logic as often as desired without having to prompt user to download a new version of our app. The deployed app is very simple and does not require update, each time the app launch it will try to load the javascripts and contents from the web.

This requirement is from marketing and they think it is fantastic if the app can be updated in this way. I don't know if this is a good idea, or even feasible.

My questions

1. Give me some reasons if this is not a good idea/not feasible
2. If javascript can be dynamically loaded, what about html and css files?

**Edit**

When I asked this question, I had not heard of [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), the idea of hybrid app was quite new at that time. With Cordova, we can write app that runs in this way. The web content (HTML/JS/CSS) is rendered in a WebView control and can be updated from the web each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I don't believe the app can be written in this way.

The application code is part of the appx package when the app is deployed and if you wish it to be accessible via the store, it has to pass MS's app certification checks.

This ensures that the app code is is suitable quality and ticks the appropriate security boxes etc.

I don't believe you can dynamically load application code from a remote source, otherwise you could be loading any old unverified cack and this code would not have been checked.

However, the updating mechanisms are very simple as I understand it and pushing a new version of your app code to the store will allow users to update the app at their leisure and handle the process for you.

I think the best you can get in terms of loading things dynamically would be to load a webpage remotely in your app (the webpage could be updated as you wanted). This would not allow you to run application code from the webpage, and with the webpage being remote, it would run under the 'web context' from a security perspective, so you'd not be able to use a lot of the native functionality you could run locally.
If the reason for re-developing the app in JS/HTML is to load code dynamically, I would advise against it. There are not a huge range of differences between a C# implementation and a JS implementation, so it would seem inefficient to redo all the existing work in a different language.